# Django ManyToManyField in a custom template?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to create a custom object adding template. I did the title, description etc. part but I could not figure out the manytomanyfield thing.

This is my views:

```
def add_product(request):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if form.is_valid():
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.user = request.user

        at = slugify(form.cleaned_data['title'])
        if at in sluglist:
            n = 0
            while at in sluglist:
                n += 1
                at = slugify(form.cleaned_data['title'])+str(n)
            product.slug = at
            sluglist.append(product.slug)
            product.active = True
            product.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/%s'%(product.slug))
        else:
            product.slug = slugify(form.cleaned_data['title'])
            sluglist.append(product.slug)
            product.active = True
            product.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/%s'%(product.slug))


    return render_to_response("products/add.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"



class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-order']

    def get_absolute_url(self, ):
        return reverse('single_product', args=[self.slug])
```

This is my admin.py:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('title',)}
    class Meta:
        model = Category

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)




class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__','description','price','order','live_link')

    inlines = [TagInline, ProductImageInline]
    search_fields = ['title','description','price', 'tag__tag']
    list_filter = ['price', 'timestamp', 'updated']
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('title',)}

    readonly_fields = ['live_link', 'timestamp', 'updated']

    class Meta:
        model = Product


    def live_link(self,obj):
        link = "<a href='/products/" + str(obj.slug)+ "/'>" + obj.title + "<a/>"
        return link

    live_link.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'categories')
```

and this is my add.html(adding thing)

```
<form method='POST' action='' >
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Başlık" class="form-control" name="title" value="" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                <textarea type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" name="description" value="" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control" name="price" value="" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <select multiple="multiple" name="categories" id="id_categories">
            {% for cat in categories %}
            <option>{{ cat }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
<input type='submit' value='Kaydet/Save' class="btn btn-info"/>

</form>
```

Without categories part in forms.py and add.html it works but I want to add category selection too. 
When I add category part that I include in codes above, it does not save the form and does not add an object. 
How can I solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The  tag in gets its value not from the Elements between the tag (which populate the menu), but from the 'value' attribute in the tag itself.  You need to change this line:

```
<option>{{ cat }}</option>
```

to this:

```
<option value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat}}</option>
```

The ModelChoiceField (the formfield used by ManyToMany objects) is expecting a model id number (although you can choose to use another model field with the 'to_field_name' attribute).  Without the 'value' attribute in the option tag, the ModelChoiceField never receives a valid value, which is why the model never saves.

See [the documentation on ModelChoiceFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) for more information.

Comment: Is this value thing valid for Django 1.5? Because I click the documentation link that you provided and changed it to version 1.5 and there was nothing about it. Also I changed the code to this but it still does not work.

Comment: The value attribute is actually not a django issue, but an [html](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) one -- in html <option> tags, it is the _value_ that is sent to the server, rather than the text between the tags themsevles.

Comment: Ok, I got that. As I said, I changed the code to one you gave but it still don't work. What else I can do?

Comment: I just realized another problem -- ModelMultipleChoiceField (and regular ModelChoiceField) also take a queryset as a mandatory argument.  Without that, it won't know which objects to validate.  So you need to add something to your form like `categories=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all())`

Comment: I put this: categories=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all()) - it said categories is not defined. Then I put categories=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.categories.objects.all()) - now it says 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'objects'. However I put categories=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all()) -  It did not raise any error but it did not work for saving category.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm looking at it, I'm not sure why you'd need the ModelMultipleChoiceField in the form at all. If the Product model already had a categories field, there's no need to define the field again in your form - just list 'categories' in your 'fields' list, and let the ModelForm do the rest of the work. Extra fields you add to the ModelForm usually **don't** get saved to the model.

Comment: I use it because I want a form with custom css. When I do it with form.as_p it renders an ugly form. I used this method for title description and price as you can see but categories part is not working.

Comment: I understand that, but you're missing my point. Do you notice how you didn't add `title=forms.CharField()` into your form? That's because the ModelForm creates the proper field in the form **from your model** - simply from adding 'title' to your list of fields in the form. This is true whether you user form.as_p or your own H TML/CSS. It will automatically associate the field with your model. The same thing will happen with categories - by adding another field with that name in the form, you're actually overriding the one with the actual relationship to the model.

Comment: So, u say my form.py should be like this: 

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = Product
  fields = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'categories')
 
right? I did it but still same.